# 'more' vs 'the more' - "I doubt this the more because.."

Tags: articles, comparison, modifiers

> [[Last Para](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_v_Hughes#Judgment), J Blackburn's judgment:] The difference is the same as that between buying a horse believed to be sound, and buying one believed to be warranted sound; but I doubt if it was made obvious to the jury, and I **doubt** this **the more** because I do not see much evidence to justify a finding for the defendant on this latter ground if the word “old” was not used. There may have been more evidence than is stated in the case; and the demeanour of the witnesses may have strengthened the impression produced by the evidence there was; but it does not seem a very satisfactory verdict if it proceeded on this latter ground. I agree, therefore, in the result that there should be a new trial.

Why not simply **more**? I guess that it modifies the bolded **doubt**. Please explain this? Is it an  adverb?

Comment: A [related question at ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3944/what-are-sentences-like-the-longer-x-the-more-y-called-and-can-they-be-used-i/3945#3945), concerning comparative construction, with a good answer by RedDwight.

Answer (score 3):

**Meaning**

**The -** (*adverb*) used before comparative adjectives or adverbs for emphasis.

**Example -**

> She looks **the** happier for her trip.

In your sentence - **...I doubt this the more...** - *more* is a comparative adverb. And that *the* before *more*, is used to give an emphasis.

Answer (score 3):

**The** here is an adverb. According to the definition at Merriam-Webster,

> (2.1) **THE** - *adverb*.
>   "than before :  than otherwise". Used before a comparative:
>         *none **the** wiser for attending*
>   (2.2)
>   **a** :  "to what extent"
>    ***the*** sooner the better
>   **b** :  "to that extent"
>    *the sooner **the** better*

According to the definition at Wiktionary:

> (2.2) **THE**: *adverb*.
>   With a comparative, and often with **for it**, indicates a result more like said comparative. This can be negated with **none**.
>   *It was a difficult time, but I’m **the** wiser for it.*
>   *It was a difficult time, and I’m none **the** wiser for it.*
>   *I'm much **the** wiser for having had a difficult time like that.*

**The** modifies the adverb **more** and they together form an adverbial [modifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_modifier) that modifies the verb **doubt**.

According to Wiktionary, [the etymology is as follows](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/the#Etymology_2):

> From Middle English, from Old English **[þȳ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%BEy#Old_English)** (“by that, after that, whereby”), originally the [instrumental case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumental_case) of the demonstratives **sē** (masculine) and **þæt** (neuter).

Imagine that **þȳ** has survived in the Modern English:

> John: It was me who extinguished this fire. The rain has nothing to do with this.
>   Paul: I doubt this.
>   John: Yes! I extinguished it **þȳ** blacke hose! (with that black hose; points at the hose)
>   Paul: I doubt this **þȳ** more! (I doubt this [to that extent] more; see Merriam-Webster's def. 2.2; the extent of his doubt has increased "by that amount" due to John's lie - by some unmeasurable amount that corresponds with Paul's astonishment at John's lie)
>   John: Why?
>   Paul: The hose is not connected to water supply!

Here, **þȳ** is used to enhance the meaning and is roughly synonymous with **even**.

---

This use of **the** as adverb occurs in comparative constructions, where **the** modifies some comparative word like "more, less" etc. In some such constructions, we can drop **the**:

> Her mood wasn't **any (the) less** bright for her loneliness.

Answer (score 2):

It is an ancient relic: the instrumental case is preserved in the comparative/superlative.

Comment: Agree. Modern version might easily be "I doubt this even more..."

Comment: Minor point, but salient. Do you consider he used 'the' for emphasis, or was it simply the correct form for its time?

Comment: Hard to say. One would have to know a lot more about 19th century books on usage than I do in order to determine whether "the more" was perceived at the time as being supplanted (and there was an effort to preserve its use). But 'the more' has long been in natural use with the comparative. As you mentioned above, nowadays it is rarer, and is replaced with 'even', though we do still hear "all the more".

Comment: ah, indeed - & 'never the less', one of those odd ones that survived by being concatenated, like nonetheless, notwithstanding, howbeit, etc

Comment: It would be great to have a bigger answer or an answer with references. I've read that some call **the** with superlatives and comparatives "a modifier" but haven't heard about the *instrumental case* thing. The downvote is not by me though. I'll try to google it up now..

Comment: See "the more, the merrier" here: http://projects.iq.harvard.edu/cb45/pages/old-english-inflection-survivors-replacements

Comment: That's a great link. I always wondered why/if **'em** applied to *him*.