# How does 'the better to ——' equate with 'So as to —— better'?

Tags: grammar

> [7. the better to ——](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/better)   = 
>         So as to —— better:

[This comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/47778/what-does-the-noun-foil-mean-in-a-foil-for-a-justices-rhetorical-gambit#comment88771_47824) revealed this grammatical confusion of mine.

1. On the left-hand side (abbreviated as LHS) above, 'the better' is a noun.

2. Yet on the right-hand side, 'better' is an adverb, modifying the infinitive 'to ——' ? This contradicts 1?
3. Also, 'so as to' just seems to have adventitiously appeared, since it's absent on the LHS?

So how can these two phrases be equal?

Comment: Is "*the better*" on the LHS really a noun? It seems more like the comparative in "*the more, the better*"…

Comment: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/38977/more-vs-the-more-i-doubt-this-the-more-because/38980#38980

Comment: [Little Red Riding Hood](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/49482/6700) might shed _some_ light on what you're asking. TRomano's point might be the deepest explanation.

Comment: "So how can these two phrases be equal?" Because native speakers of English accept them as being equal.

Answer (score 1):

Well, *the better* on the LHS is not a noun.  It's an adverbial phrase.

*The better to eat you with,* for example, is not a complete sentence.  It has no subject.

Comment: And the "so as to..." simply clarifies that this is adverbial (it means "in a manner that...")

Comment: Actually, it's debatable whether "All the better to eat you with" is a complete sentence. It's like "Off with his head!" This kind of thing throws linguists and grammarians into a tizzy, but not native speakers. One can _argue_ that it lacks a subject, or lacks a verb, or whatever. But those are only arguments based on theories about the language, which could easily be wrong, or these very sentence forms could be exceptions.

Comment: How old are you?  Answer: Eighteen. - The question whether "eighteen" is a sentence  does not make much sense. It is a complete answer and it is self-evident that this is a shortening of "I am eighteen". But in answers  the shortest answer is preferred as speaking is articulation work. - So when Little Red Riding Hood says: " Grandmother, what big teeth you have "  the Wolf does not answer:  "I have big teeth all the better to eat you with" but only "(all) the better to eat you with". - By the way, this "the2" is not identical with the normal article "the".  (See etymonline  the).