# difference between "better" and "all the better"?

Tags: difference

Tell me please what the difference between the following sentences.

> You do your job well, but if you do it my way, it would be **better**.
>
> You do your job well, but if you do it my way, it would be **all the better.**

Comment: Does [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/49482/109190) help?

Answer (score 1):

better is a comparative, standard grammar

Example: It would be better [as opposed to good or best] if you did this rather than that.

"all the better" is just colloquial, spoken language and idiomatic.

[website containing a list of idioms from a former ESL teacher called Kate](https://www.learn-english-today.com/idioms/idiom-alphalists/alpha-list_A/id_A3-allalong-allrage.html)

all the better for (something)
If you are all the better for something, you benefit from it or feel much better as a result of it.
"You'll be all the better for a good night's rest."

On the link  page, you can click on the letter she has written to users.

Answer (score 1):

In ***the* better** we have a relict instrumental with adverbial force which can be paraphrased using the preposition **by**: by that much the better, by so much the better.  In ***all* the better**, the word **all** means "entirely or completely".  The upshot: the improvement is receiving greater approbation relative to the simple **better**. It could be paraphrased as *even better*.

Comment: Too complex for my taste. That said,  "All the better" cannot be broken up in order to understand it.

Comment: All the more reason to point out that in constructions like this, ***all the*** is an ***intensifier***. Every now and then you find yourself needing to go further than ***better***, but not so far as ***best***. In which context I've definitely heard things like *I feel **much more betterer** now, thanks.*

Comment: @Lambie: But "it's just colloquial" doesn't quite do it justice. Language changes over time. English used to be a declined language, like German, with nominative, dative, accusative, instrumental, and genitive cases. We still have some vestigial cases, and some fossils like this.

Comment: I see no reason to go overboard at this level.  The big bad wolf said; The better to see you with but also: all the better to see you with. Depending on the translation.

Comment: @Lambie: All you said in your answer was  that **all the better** "is just colloquial".  Sometimes a little complexity is better than an oversimplification.